# Challenges with Celery: Managing Long-Running Tasks and Communication Loss in Solo Mode

Tags: python, django, celery

Good day to all. I've encountered an intriguing issue. I've developed a microservice using Celery that communicates with the main application through REDIS, where the main application also uses Celery. The problem is that I had to run the microservice worker in solo mode because certain functionalities don't operate properly in the regular mode (it's quite complex to explain what and why). Due to the solo mode and the extended task execution time, there is a loss of communication between the workers, causing tasks to re-enter the queue. This occurs because Celery assumes something has gone wrong when the worker doesn't respond for an extended period (tasks take up to 5 hours to complete). Increasing the task execution waiting time isn't feasible, as tasks re-enter the queue due to connection disruption. To avoid tasks re-entering the queue, the heartbeat was disabled. Despite my efforts, tasks still repetitively re-enter the queue even if the process is ongoing

My Settings:

```
app.conf.broker_connection_timeout = 10

app.conf.broker_connection_retry = 10

app.conf.result_extended = True

app.conf.task_acks_late = True

app.conf.task_track_started = True

app.conf.task_publish_retry = False
app.conf.broker_transport_options = {"visibility_timeout": 86400}

app.conf.worker_max_memory_per_child = 10000


app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

The following solutions to the problem were tried, but they did not help

1. Running the microservice worker in solo mode due to issues encountered in the regular mode.
2. Disabling the heartbeat to prevent tasks from re-entering the queue.
3. Attempts to maintain communication between the workers to prevent tasks from re-entering the queue

Comment: Looks like this is an issue with solo mode https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/3430 Are you sure you can't run it with threads and concurrency set to 1 ?

Comment: @arrmansa, Yes, solo mod and concurrency is set to 1

Comment: No I mean can you try running it with pool=threads and concurrency=1. It should have almost the exact same behaviour as solo and might fix your problem.

Comment: @arrmansa I am running my Celery worker using pool=solo to avoid script hanging. I have scripted a 3D model rendering tool, but during the launch and reading of the .blend file, the script simply hangs, and I don't know what to do. However, when I run it in solo mode, everything works. I tried specifying --pool=threads --concurrency=1, but I received the message "Segmentation fault (core dumped).

Comment: maybe pool=prefork and --concurrency=1 could work?

Comment: @arrmansa No, I use python bpy (Blender API) this is a fairly heavy module that can load the system heavily